# Python script fails to scrap website using googletrans library and panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, google-translate

I need some help, i have a script that translate title course and name. I am using pandas that uses data frame but its fails to compile and will share the issue i am getting on terminal.

// Terminal Error

> ```
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Zux\PycharmProjects\ClassCentral\ClassCentral\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
> data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Zux\PycharmProjects\ClassCentral\ClassCentral\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
> token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Zux\PycharmProjects\ClassCentral\ClassCentral\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
> self._update()
> File "C:\Users\Zux\PycharmProjects\ClassCentral\ClassCentral\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
> code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

// Code implementation for using libraries

```
`from googletrans import Translator
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request as urllib2
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.classcentral.com/collection/top-free-online-courses"
driver.get(url)

translator = Translator()

try:
    while True:
        # wait until button is clickable
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-name='LOAD_MORE']"))
        ).click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
except Exception as e:
    pass

all_courses = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='catalog-grid__results')
courses = all_courses.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[class="color-charcoal course-name"]')

df = pd.DataFrame([[course.text, course.get_attribute('href')] for course in courses],
                  columns=['Title (eng)', 'Link'])

df['Title (hin)'] = df['Title (eng)'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='hi').text)

print(df)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working with bit of re-looking at all site-packages carefully and done the following to make it work.

1. pip uninstall googletrans
2. pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
3. df['Title (hin)'] = df['Title (eng)'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='hi').text)
4. See output below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvmJ.png)